# Efficient way to store screen size, origin, and other global variables in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am building a 2d game using Cocos2d-x V3.x

I was wondering, what would be the best method to store the screen size variable, origin variable and others that can remain constant throughout the whole game?

For example:

```
Size windowSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 windowOrigin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
```

I believe these can be set as global variables.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Is the controversial singleton the best way?

Or should I just let each .cpp file have its own windowSize variables each time the scene is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do it, if you want to use one variable to use in all the scenes you can do it following way.

```
//in header
class BaseScene : public Scene
{
protected:
    Size windowSize;
    Vec2 windowOrigin;

};

//cpp file
BaseScene::BaseScene() {

    windowSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    windowOrigin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
}
```

Now extend every scene from BaseScene class and directly use variable `windowSize` and `windowOrigin`

Answer (score 1):

I just create a very simple header file.

```
/*
* Constants.h
*
*  Created on: Jul 2, 2016
*      Author: OscarLeif
*/

#ifndef CONSTANTS_H_
#define CONSTANTS_H_

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"

#define CENTER_VECTOR Vec2(Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().width*0.5f,Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().height*0.5f)
#define WIN_SIZE Director::getInstance()->getWinSize()

USING_NS_CC;
using namespace ui;

class Constants
{
public:
    Constants();
    virtual ~Constants();
};

#endif /* CONSTANTS_H_ */
```

This is just one way to do it. Just call Constanst.h and you will have static global variables

```
#include "Constants.h"

bool BaseScene::init()
{
  if(!Layer::init())
     return false;
  //Some Sprite that you have already created
  sprite->setPosition(CENTER_VECTOR);//
}
```